# Stuck while seeking $a$ with which the difference between quadratic roots is above 3

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

The problem is:

> Find the values of **a** with which the roots of the following inequality will form an interval longer than 3:
>
> $$x^2-(a^2+3a+1)x+a^2+3a^3\le0$$

From Vieta's formulas, the square of the difference of the roots of a reduced quadratic ($x^2+px+q=0$) is
$$(x_1-x_2)^2=p^2-4q$$

Thus, I decided for starters to derive $a$ from

$$(x_1-x_2)^2=9$$

$$p^2-4q=(a^2+3a+1)^2-4(a^2+3a^3)=a^4-6a^3+7a^2+6a+1$$

But I've no idea how to solve the

$$a^4-6a^3+7a^2+6a+1=9$$

Maybe there is a simpler way?

---

P.S.
$\checkmark$ The textbook's answer is

[image]

Comment: Isn't your $q = a^2 + 3a^3$? Else your calculation is wrong

Comment: @CopperKettle The point is in the powers. So $q=a^2+3a^3$, not $a^2+3a^2$ as you wrote.

Comment: @5xum - oh, thank you! I've fixed it. It's indeed in the third power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to solve the equation

$$a^4 - 6a^3 + 7a^2+6a-8 = 0$$

My advice is you first try to guess at least one root of the polynomial.

**Hints**:

1. There exists a rational root of the above polynomial.
2. There is a very handy theorem for finding rational roots of polynomials.
3. Try to plug in the simplest possible values for $a$ that you can think of...

Comment: Yeah! Thanks! The value of *$a=1$* worked like a charm! (*googles for "rational roots theorem polynomials"*)

Comment: @CopperKettle Then you reduced the polynomial to order $3$. Another rational root can also be found there...

Comment: @CopperKettle Did you find the remaining roots?

Comment: no, haven't found them yet.. judging by [this](http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~cs577/handouts/polyroots.pdf), there has to be 4 roots

Comment: @CopperKettle Which numbers did you try? Did you reduce the polynomial to order $3$?

Comment: At this moment, I'm reading up on "rational zeros theorem" (point 2 in your answer) (0: Is this the way to reduce it: $a^4-6a^3+7a^2+6a+1=a(a^3-6a^2+7a+6)+1$

Comment: @CopperKettle Do you know about Horner's method?

Comment: I did not. Thank you for the mention, I'll read up on it. I've found some info on [reducing polynomials](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/polynomials-solving.html) when one root is known, am reading it.

Comment: @CopperKettle Well, Horner's method is precisely reducing polynomials when one root is known. I suggest you study that as well, it is very useful for your current problem.

Comment: @CopperKettle Also, I find it very strange that a class would demand you to know how to find all roots of a fourth degree polynomial without knowing Horners method.

Comment: There's no class, I'm teaching myself. (0: Found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxdoe19UXVE) on Horner's method and polynomial long division. (0:

Comment: I finally made it! $(a+1)(a-1)(a-2)(a-4)$! A great method. I wonder why I don't recall ever using it in school. And there's a [great calculator](http://www.mathportal.org/calculators/polynomials-solvers/polynomial-factoring-calculator.php) to check on one's results.

Comment: @CopperKettle If you went through high school, you learned Horners method. You just forgot it.